# Deploy keycloak custom spi deployment

Tags: jboss, wildfly, redhat, keycloak, ear

I try to create a custom spi, in my keycloak project, following the basic keycloack structure, I add custom provider interface which extends provider, custom provider factory and implement custom spi for them as keycloak documentation says, and they do in their source code, after that i create a custom implementation for my provider and provider factory, i create the file in META-INF/services as documentation says, and I am using ear aproach to deploy like in beercloak example, but when I try to use my provider in code null pointer exception is thrown, this only happens when I try to add a custom spi, if I am implementing aprovider which has an existing keycloak spi it works, it also works if I am using the modules aproach, where i create a new module with jboss-cli, but that aproach seems hard to maintain, anyone has any ideas why this happens and how can I solve it or what is the best approach, thanks.

> 08:43:48,264 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-1) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at sso.authentication.forms.RegistrationProfile.validate(RegistrationProfile.java:55)
>           at org.keycloak.authentication.FormAuthenticationFlow.processAction(FormAuthenticationFlow.java:214)
>           at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processAction(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:99)
>           at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticationAction(AuthenticationProcessor.java:873)
>           at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:296)
>           at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processRegistration(LoginActionsService.java:631)
>           at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.registerRequest(LoginActionsService.java:685)
>           at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processRegister(LoginActionsService.java:665)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:355)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:137)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:100)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:355)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>           at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:90)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>           at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
>           at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>           at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you update your question with the error logs you received. So that it will be helpful for the people to understand where you making mistake or to point out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you look closely in the `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalon-ha.xml` or `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalon.xml` files, you'll notice these lines somewhere:

```xml
<providers>
    <provider>classpath:${jboss.home.dir}/providers/*</provider>
</providers>
```

which means, that you need to have your compiled files inside a folder in the root, `${jboss.home.dir}/providers/` before their `SPI` could be registered.

Doing this is basically the same as adding a new line with the path to your module here such as

```xml
<providers>
    <provider>classpath:${jboss.home.dir}/providers/*</provider>
    <provider>module:com/selast/keycloak-provider/*</provider>
</providers>
```

Hope it helps soomeone, as I've spent a day on it .

Comment: Thanks for this find. But I don't have any providers folder inside my jboss directory. I cannot paste the entire search result here but these are the closes paths, ./opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/keycloak.v2/admin/resources/realm-settings/key-providers. or where other providers are ./opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider.   Please advice